# 404 -The requested resource is not available. (Spring-mvc)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I am not very familiar with Spring MVC view resolver.I am trying to return a JSP from my controller.
My Controller method is getting executed properly but when returning view, i am getting `404 -The requested resource is not available` error.

this is entry in my `servlet-context.xml` file

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

this is how, i have defined resource structure

```
webapp
  --WEB-INF
      --views
         --shop
           --common
             --cart
                myjsp.jsp
```

This is how, i am returning JSP view from controller

```
private final static String MYVIEW="shop/common/cart/myjsp";
@RequestMapping(value={"/shop/myMethod.html"},  method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
     return MYVIEW;
 }
```

this is my application home page URL

```
http://localhost:7777/my-shop/shop/
```

not sure where i am doing worng.

*Edit*
We are using Tiles with spring and have seen this additional information

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="viewClass">
    <beans:value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</beans:value>               
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
  <beans:property name="definitions">
    <beans:list>
      <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-admin.xml</beans:value>
      <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-shop.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Not sure how i can add additional view resolver?

error

The requested resource `(/my-shop/WEB-INF/views/shop/common/cart/myjsp.jsp)` is not available.
I noted down one more strange things, few JSPs under `WEB-INF/views` are accessible but when I placed new JSP on same location it is not working and giving same error.

Comment: This is certainly a confusing factor, when starting with spring MVC you should carefully follow all the instructions, You can better follow some tutorial like "http://blog.manishchhabra.com/2013/03/hello-world-with-spring-web-mvc-3-2/", "http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/"

Comment: I suppose `myjsp.jsp` and `mincart.jsp` are the same?

Comment: @Alex: yes that is true :)

Comment: One more confusing factor is your request is for html file and I noticed a jsp file there, I don't know whether it will work or not

Comment: @Suganthan: URL mapping is for the URL and not for any resource, this will only work as a URL mapper

Comment: show us your `web.xml`, please.

Answer (score 2):

I can help you to catch some points,where I found the difficulty

1. In your web.xml configure the correct path of servlet-context.xml under context-param
2. In servlet-context.xml under context:component-scan base-package="/youcontrollerclass"/ - check whether you have given right path
3. Dependency files in POM.xml

this is part of my servlet-context.xml

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="mypath"/>

     <bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if your view is throwing an error, then you'll get a 404, even though the controller/view/JSP files are there. Try increasing your Spring logging level or attaching a remote debugger. I had the same issue last week and the 404 was at first misleading.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Maven->Update project resolved the issue! I know its relatively irrelevant, but it might someone someday!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use multiples view resolvers; however you have not specified the order. I am guessing thats why it is giving 404. Try this:

**NOTE:The ViewResolver with the highest order is the last resolver in the chain.**

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  <beans:property name="order" value = "0" />
</beans:bean>


 <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="viewClass">
    <beans:value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</beans:value>               
  </beans:property>
<beans:property name="order" value = "1" />
</beans:bean>
```